# Convert 'int' to pytorch 'Variable' makes problems

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

First project with pytorch and I got stuck trying to convert an MNIST label 'int' into a torch 'Variable'. Debugger says it has no dimension?!

```
# numpy mnist data
X_train, Y_train = read_data("training")
X_test , Y_test  = read_data("testing")

arr = np.zeros(5)
for i in range(5):
    # in your training loop:
    costs_ = 0
    for k in range(10000):
        optimizer.zero_grad()                            # zero the gradient buffers
        a = torch.from_numpy(np.expand_dims(X_train[k].flatten(), axis=0)).float()
        b = torch.from_numpy(np.array(Y_train[k], dtype=np.float)).float()
        input = Variable(a)
        output = net(input)
        target = Variable(b)                             # PROBLEM!!
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()                                 # Does the update

        costs_ += loss.data.numpy()
    arr[i] = costs_ 
    print(i)
```

Thrown error is: "RuntimeError: input and target have different number of elements: input[1 x 1] has 1 elements, while target[] has 0 elements at /b/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THNN/generic/MSECriterion.c:12"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what is happening. Your `target` variable is empty.

**Edit (after the comment below):**

if `Y_train[k] = 5`, then `np.array(Y_train[k], dtype=np.float).shape = ()`, and in turn `Variable(b)` becomes a tensor with no dimension.

In order to fix this you will need to pass a list to `np.array()` and not a integer or a float.

Like this:

```
b = torch.from_numpy(np.array([Y_train[k]], dtype=np.float)).float()
```

Comment: No it is not empty. When I do "print(Y_train[k])" I see the "5" in the terminal...

Comment: I have edited the answer. This should definitely be it. Also I would request you to edit your question with the following information for future readers: the dimension of the inputs `X_train`, `Y_train`, `X_test` and `Y_test`, and the dimension of the `output`.